# Javascript React Component with 2 returns depending on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component and have a condition on it.

I want to have a different return jsx depending on the condition result.

This is what I've got but it's only returning the last one.

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: sessionStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn'),
      redirect: false,
    };
  }

  render() {

    if (!this.state.isLoggedIn) {

      return (
        <div>
          <h1>You are NOT logged in</h1>
        </div>
      );

    } else {

      return (
        <div>
          <h1>You ARE logged in</h1>);
        </div>

    }
  }
}

export default Login;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks more likely that your `sessionStorage` is not working.

Comment: Why isn't `isLoggedIn` in the `state` object?

Comment: @dogui I've added the sessionStorage to the state but it's still always showing the same return

Comment: How do you know session storage is working? What happens when you log `isLoggedIn` in the `render`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, false is saved in sessionStorage corresponding to **isLoggedIn**

You should use:

```
this.state = {
  isLoggedIn: sessionStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true',
  redirect: false,
}
```

values stored in sessionStorage are string. So, **false** will be stored as **'false'**. So, **this.state.isLoggedIn** is always true.

Answer (score 1):

You have a closing bracket in the wrong place, for one. It should be after `div` and not `h1`. BTW, There is no need for the 2nd return.

`render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>You are { (!this.state.isLoggedIn) ? 'NOT' : '' } logged in</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }`

Comment: I need 2 different div structures

Comment: you are returning one, either way. how is your version functionally different? you just have more code to accomplish the same thing, right?